# <img> in <table> without any spaces

Tags: html, image, html-table

I am trying to put two images side by side inside a `<td>` (also tried one `<td>` for each img), but has some white spaces between the images, and do not understand where they come .. I can solve my problem using float, but I'm trying to avoid this. If someone can explain to me why this happens. I took some tips from other questions, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style "text/css">
        td, tr, img  { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: none; }
        table { border-collapse: collapse;} 
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background: black;">
    <center>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img alt="" title="" src="http://i.min.us/ijCTdY.jpg" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img alt="" title="" src="http://i.min.us/jj7Yt6.jpg"/>
                    <img alt="" title="" src="http://i.min.us/ijCo96.jpg"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
```

you can notice that the top image has 800 px height, and the other ones has 400px each one, what I need is some kinda square, without any spaces between the images.

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/xMW7N/

Comment: You don't need the `center` tag. It's also been deprecated. Use `margin: auto`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/xMW7N/1/

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that you are using [layout tables](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`img`s are inline elements. The horizontal space between the images is coming from the whitespace between the images in the HTML. The same reason that there's a space between the characters [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XUd64/).

So, to fix that, remove the whitespace: http://jsfiddle.net/xMW7N/2/

The vertical space is also because the images are inline elements. The gap is the space reserved for descenders in letters like `g` and `j`.

To fix that, set `vertical-align: top` on `img`: http://jsfiddle.net/xMW7N/3/

Although in your case (as mentioned in your question), setting  `float: left` works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/xMW7N/4/

That works because `float: left` forces `display: block`, so all of the problems caused by the images being inline are resolved.

Comment: i can't even imagine that a line feed was considereted as whitespace. why? it's confusing to me.

Comment: @Felipe Silva: Any "whitespace characters" (spaces, tabs, line feeds) are collapsed into one space. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/7fZpF/. As you can see, the distance between the images is the same despite the varying amounts of whitespace in the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

It's the whitespace in your markup itself. If you remove the line-break and the spaces between the two images, the space will go away.

The whitespace is treated as text, as a single space character.

Comment: i can't even imagine that a line feed was considereted as whitespace.

Comment: In HTML, all whitespace (line breaks, spaces, tabs) are considered whitespace when you're working with text. All consecutive whitespace is combined and rendered into a single space character. This is why you need `<p>` tags or forced line breaks when using paragraphs of text - if you just have line breaks between paragraphs, they'll all run together, with just a single space separating them.

Answer (score 3):

This is easier done without tables: http://jsfiddle.net/feSxA/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: black;
    }
    .imgHolder { 
        width: 800px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .imgHolder img {
        float: left;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="imgHolder">
        <img alt="" title="" src="http://i.min.us/ijCTdY.jpg" />
        <img alt="" title="" src="http://i.min.us/jj7Yt6.jpg" />
        <img alt="" title="" src="http://i.min.us/ijCo96.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: However, why did you preserve the `center` tag?

Comment: ok, that solves the problem, but, i think is not the best way to use float. Must be a way to not use float.

Comment: @Felipe Silva: There's nothing whatsoever wrong with using floats. However, if you're determined, see my answer for a fix not involving floats..

Comment: @Felipe - That's an unusual statement given your code includes a `center` tag and `table`'s for layout. There isn't anything wrong with this approach that I can see (except the `center` tag that is still in this answer, which should be removed IMO).

Comment: @Jared - I'm tired and it was there already!  I'll edit to use the proper way

Comment: Or not, @thirtydot beat me to it :)

Comment: I missed the table-based layout at first, so between the two of us we'd be gold. :D

Answer (score 0):

try adding a border="0" in your table element

Answer (score 0):

**Add `display: block;` to your images.**

This will remove any gaps caused by the image being inline but you may need to split the cells up to allow them to sit side by side.

*You can also remove the whitespace which should get rid of the whitespace.*

Comment: Won't that will just put the images on top of each other?

Comment: I think you would also want to `float: left/right`: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/xMW7N/5/