# Why does webkit (Chrome/Safari) render wonky focus on this element?

Tags: css, webkit, focus

I've created a custom HTML combo box. Everything's working good except Webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari) render the focus highlight wonky. Here's what it looks like on Chrome and Safari:

[image: Focus as rendered in Chrome]

Notice the protruding focus border on the bottom of the drop down image.

Here's the same thing in IE and Firefox:

[image: Focus rendered in Firefox]

[image: Focus rendered in IE9]

As you can see, IE and Firefox both render the focus using a nice rectangle, but Chrome renders it wonky.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div style="height:32px;" class="ko-select-container" tabindex=0>
    <div class="selected-option">
        <span>Select a Value</span>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <!-- Drop down image height is 32px !-->
        <img src="DropDown.png" />
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `vertical-align: top` to the `img`. That gap looks suspiciously like the [usual problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975623/img-in-table-without-any-spaces/6975674#6975674).

Comment: You're a mensch! So easy, don't know why I didn't think of this. Thanks! (I'll mark yours as the answer as soon as SO allows me.)