# There is always a little space under images inside a table

Tags: css

I'll provide direct link for people who wants to see it live.

Just hover one of the table listing and you'll see there is always a small space under images. I've tried padding, margin, searched stackoverflow for it and used border spacing, border collapse etc. but nothing helped so far.

I would like your help. What's the problem and what am I missing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Problem isn't the table actually, img tags are inline elements and have that bottom spacing by default (something with line-height I guess, don't really know why).

Solution: `div.browseBuilds tr.browseBuilds_piece img { display: block; }`

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue. Going to select it as answer in 2 minutes.

Comment: `img` tags have no default bottom spacing. Just the whitespace characters in the HTML source code are displayed, because `img` is an inline elment by default.

Comment: @LyverKinkki See other possibble fixes on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image/13961130

Comment: When I use "display:block" property, it is working fine but my text-align: center is not working. I am creating an email template.

Answer (score 4):

Add display: block to img.

```
    .browseBuilds_piece img{
       display:block
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

User cellpadding="0" and cellspacing="0" as a table attribute.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
```

Comment: How can I write those attributes in css? Edit: I applied it, but it is still the same.

Comment: table { 
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be cellspacing and cellpadding but im not sure ... really good tool for this stuff is firebug , inspect element you will see all used styles etc.. or try to fix td height on 50px like your img

Comment: I've got firebug installed on my Firefox but I don't know how to inspect something. I'm using Firefox's default inspect function. Can you tell me a bit about it?

Comment: click with right mouse button on element and than chose inspect element in firebug there will be blue icon ;-) than firebug will appear with html structure and if you click on some element styles will appear on right side

Answer (score 1):

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975623/img-in-table-without-any-spaces). Because `img` is an inline element, whitespaces in the HTML source code around the `img` tag matter and will be displayed. Either remove the whitespaces from the code

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle;"><img src="./themes/default/images/builds/eski.jpg"></td>
```

or display the `img` as a block element, as [Michal has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14626127/1231686).

Comment: I think vertical-align: middle is a good property to remove whitespace. text-align: center is not working while I am using display: block